# Is there any way to simulate multiple iOS devices running a Bonjour networking app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, bonjour

I want to build a multiplayer iPhone game that allows multiple iPhones (clients) to connect to a single iPad (server) using Bonjour. Since I only have one iPhone and one iPad, is there a way to run multiple instances of the iPhone simulator to simulate the multiplayer app?

If not, does anyone have any creative solutions to testing a multiplayer game with a limited number of iOS devices?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: If you separate out the UI from the backend logic that's taking to the server, maybe you could build a 'bot that runs on MacOS and makes multiple server connections. The UI layer's all different, but the Bonjour & networking stuff is pretty consistent between iOS & Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, install multiple versions of the iOS SDK to different directories.

During the install process, set the location to a different directory. 
[image]

Comment: thanks, christo16!  question, do they have to be different versions of the SDK or can I install the same version in different locations?

Comment: You can install the same or different versions.

Comment: @christo16 Hey does this enable a user to create multiple instances of the simulator??

Comment: The simulator is just like any other app, if you've been able to install multiple copies of it, you should be able to run them simultaneously.